# Why does the host address is included in HTTP 1.1 GET command?

Tags: http

```
GET /calcuapp/calculator.jsp HTTP/1.1 
Host: 192.168.1.66:8080
```

I'm using PuTTy and the host destination is already set up on the settings. Why do I need again to type the host destination as you can see above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is Virtual Hosts.

For many years now, it has been quite common to host multiple sites/domains from a single server. HTTP 1.1 supports this by requiring the `host` header. If you use HTTP 1.0 you may leave this out.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Host`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4) HTTP header is mandatory since HTTP/1.1 and it's used for **virtual hosting**.

It must include the domain name of the server, and the TCP port number on which the server is listening. The port number may be omitted if the port is the standard port for the service requested (`80` for HTTP and `443` for HTTPS).

A HTTP/1.1 request that lacks the `Host` header should be responded with a `400` (Bad Request) status code.

---

The [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), the current reference message syntax and routing in HTTP/1.1, tells the whole story about this header:

> [**5.4.  Host**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4)
>
> The `Host` header field in a request provides the host and port
> information from the target URI, enabling the origin server to
> distinguish among resources while servicing requests for multiple
> host names on a single IP address.
>
> ```
> Host = uri-host [ ":" port ]
> ```
>
> A client MUST send a `Host` header field in all HTTP/1.1 request
> messages.  If the target URI includes an authority component, then a
> client MUST send a field-value for `Host` that is identical to that
> authority component, excluding any userinfo subcomponent and its `@`
> delimiter.  If the authority component is missing or
> undefined for the target URI, then a client MUST send a `Host` header
> field with an empty field-value.
>
> Since the `Host` field-value is critical information for handling a
> request, a user agent SHOULD generate `Host` as the first header field
> following the request-line.
>
> For example, a GET request to the origin server for
> `http://www.example.org/pub/WWW/` would begin with:
>
> ```
> GET /pub/WWW/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.example.org
> ```
>
> A client MUST send a `Host` header field in an HTTP/1.1 request even if
> the request-target is in the absolute-form, since this allows the
> `Host` information to be forwarded through ancient HTTP/1.0 proxies
> that might not have implemented `Host`.
>
> When a proxy receives a request with an absolute-form of
> request-target, the proxy MUST ignore the received `Host` header field
> (if any) and instead replace it with the host information of the
> request-target.  A proxy that forwards such a request MUST generate a
> new `Host` field-value based on the received request-target rather than
> forward the received `Host` field-value.
>
> Since the `Host` header field acts as an application-level routing
> mechanism, it is a frequent target for malware seeking to poison a
> shared cache or redirect a request to an unintended server.  An
> interception proxy is particularly vulnerable if it relies on the
> `Host` field-value for redirecting requests to internal servers, or for
> use as a cache key in a shared cache, without first verifying that
> the intercepted connection is targeting a valid IP address for that
> host.
>
> A server MUST respond with a `400` (Bad Request) status code to any
> HTTP/1.1 request message that lacks a `Host` header field and to any
> request message that contains more than one `Host` header field or a
> `Host` header field with an invalid field-value.

Answer (score 0):

Your local resolver (DNS etc) converts the host name on the command line to an IP address before connecting; there is no way for the remote server to know which host name you gave on the command line if there are multiple host names which resolve to the same IP address (this is what's called "virtual hosting"; with HTTP 1.0, you needed a separate IP address for each distinct HTTP host, which is extremely wasteful, but saves you from needing to transmit the `Host:` header).